# Is it conventional to not have author on the 2nd page?

Tags: research-proposal

I have seen an academic proposal which has the following style for headers:

- On the 1st page, there is no header.
- On the 2nd page, there is a header, but there is no author on the left
- From the 3rd page, there are always headers with author, title and page.

Could anyone tell me that if it is conventional to not have author on the 2nd page?

PS: the following code could reproduce the effects.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4]{article}

\RequirePackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}
\RequirePackage{fancyhdr}
\RequirePackage{microtype}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\setlength{\textwidth}{170mm}
\setlength{\textheight}{245mm}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{-2mm}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{-2mm}
\setlength{\hoffset}{0mm}
\setlength{\voffset}{-10mm}
\setlength{\headheight}{3mm}
\setlength{\headsep}{4mm}
\setlength{\topmargin}{-5mm}

\lhead{\lhead{Author}}
\rhead{\thepage}
\chead{Title}
% Foot
\rfoot{}
\lfoot{}
\cfoot{}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
1 \lipsum*[1]

2 \lipsum*[1]

3 \lipsum*[1]

4 \lipsum*[1]

5 \lipsum*[1]

6 \lipsum*[1]

7 \lipsum*[1]

8 \lipsum*[1]

\pagestyle{fancy}
9 \lipsum*[1]

10 \lipsum*[1]

11 \lipsum*[1]

12 \lipsum*[1]

13 \lipsum*[1]

14 \lipsum*[1]

15 \lipsum*[1]

16 \lipsum*[1]

17 \lipsum*[1]

18 \lipsum*[1]

19 \lipsum*[1]

20 \lipsum*[1]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

Questions of style are going to be specific to the institution and type of document. And possibly change over time.

If the specific style seems strange to you, you should check with somebody in the institution that will be the audience of the document.  You mention that this is for an academic proposal. That seems to mean it is a university or a granting agency or some such similar thing. Find out if there is a contact person with whom you can check such issues.